# Stop `until`-loop when condition is met

Tags: ruby, selenium, automated-tests, watir

I want to make sure the following test can't be stuck in an infinite loop.  I would like to make the loop run only a certain amount of times.

```
When /^I click the Settings link$/ do
  footer = @browser.div(:id, 'iwinbottombar')
  footer.wait_until_present
  unless footer.html.include?('Settings')
    throw Exception.new("Expected to see the settings button but it was not there")
  end
  until @browser.div(:id, 'dialogcontainer').div(:class, 'settings_browsebutton button clickable').present? do
    footer.a(:class, 'button_settings').when_present.click
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure how to limit the code to do that. I think I need a counter, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: If you are asking what you I think you are asking from the comments, read about the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want something like `while`/`until` but with maximum times of retries:

```
10.times do
  break if condition_met?
  do_whatever
end
```

Comment: No, he want's the code to run a certain **amount of time**, not a certain **number of times**.

Comment: hi, that would work, the issue is that I don't know how many tries it will take until the condition is met, so I don't want to set a definate value, I don't want the test to run anymore times than's neccessary

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, really? *"make the loop run only a certain amount of times"*.

Comment: @Ethranes, there is no way to predict how many iterations a random algorithm will need. It's called the stopping problem.

Comment: sawa edited the question and changed that :) The op initially wrote "certain amount of time".

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, actually, it asked for both ambiguously. Read the initial version.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu Nope. In one place, it said "times" in plural, in another place, it said "time" in singular. I only deleted the singular part. I did not change it. The first one in plural clearly means the number, not a time interval.

Comment: Fine, I give up :) But this case warrants a timeout, not a specific number of retries.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu Nope. I know English is not your native language, but "time**s**" in **plural** unambiguously means number of repetition, not a **single** time interval. And don't try to change the question.

Comment: Op mentioned both, and given the circumstances a time interval makes more sense. You took a guess and "fixed" the confusion in the wrong direction, most likely. *It should be up to the OP to clarify what he wants*.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu, I would argue that it doesn't make more sense as OP guesses he needs to use some sort of counter afterwards. Also he didn't object to the edit, even though he visited the question after the edit was done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the break works fine, just running that 2.times solves the problem that I was having, sorry for the shitty question.